# how to run non-static after-tests with JUnit and SpringRunner

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing

We have some methods in production code annotated with `@Transaction(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)`. Thus, annotating the test class with `@Transactional`/`@Rollback` still leads to polluted database. I would like to have method that could delete records from the relevant tables when ALL of the tests of this class have completed. However, `@AfterClass` method is bound to be static, so how could I access my Spring-provided EntityManager and/or Spring Data repositories. The solution we use at the moment is to annotate test class with `@DirtiesContext(mode=AFTER_CLASS)` however this leads to really painful experiences if you forget to also override datasource URL for this test class.

So, can this be achieved in more idiomatic Spring/JUnit manner?

Answer (score 0):

I have an regression suite which runs against QA environments. Since it exercises the application, by its very nature, it modifies the database. For these tests, I have specific test users and each test creates any records it is dependent on. During this setup and during execution of the tests, any created database records are tracked in local collection. At the end of the test, i.e. during the cleanUp method, the records are removed from the database. I also use a name and test run identifier that makes it easy to distinguish these records from real data in case of any cleanup issues. Not sure this would meet your idea of idiomatic Spring/JUnit, but this works for us and keeps our QA environment data reasonably clean.

Comment: does this cleanUp method runs after each test? If I would be happy with `@After` I would not bother posting the question. I am looking for something that runs after all tests in the class, but might be non-static

Comment: Have you looked at DbUnit? It is a Junit extension for managing database state for tests.